# Output text/numbers in MATLAB but overwrite same line in command window

Tags: matlab, formatting, printf

So I have a for-loop, and at every iteration, I would like to display formatted text, along with some numbers. Normally one could use disp or fprintf I suppose, but what I want to do, is have the *same* part of the command window output the text/numbers, just overwriting the old output.

How might I be able to do that? I have seen it in some other programs so I know it is possible, but not how.

As an example, lets say on the first iteration of a for-loop, I want this to be output on the command prompt:

```
>> Measurement1 : 0.33 0.23 0.34 -32.32
   Measurement2 : 433.2
   Text Stuff   : 'The cat who ate the rat'
```

Now, on the second iteration of the loop, I DONT want a new line or lines, I simply want the old numbers and old text to be *replaced*, in the *same* place on the command window. So on teh second iteration, I might get this:

```
>> Measurement1 : -132.3 32.1 32.23 -320.32
   Measurement2 :  3.2
   Text Stuff   : 'The dog who ate the cat'
```

Thanks

Comment: The following 'solution' describes one method: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-A9SG8Z/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-A9SG8Z

Comment: Hmm, thanks Edric, it will work I suppose, but I am open to more elegant solutions.

Comment: I think that's about as good as it gets in the MATLAB command window - I don't know of any way to handle multiple lines of text. The next option is to make a simple GUI.

Comment: You could do that using the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249639/matlab-and-math-equations-via-latex-in-command-window-or-stand-alone-plots), just clear the figure between iterations and don't keep the position of the text constant. If you run into trouble, I can provide you with sample code.

Comment: @EitanT I would very much appreciate that thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what you're looking for:

```
%# Generate the data
Measurement1 = {[0.33 0.23 0.34 -32.32]; [-132.3 32.1 32.23 -320.32]};
Measurement2 = {433.2; 3.2};
TextStuff = {'The cat who ate the rat'; 'The dog who ate the cat'};
s = cell2struct([Measurement1, Measurement2, TextStuff], ...
    {'Measurement1', 'Measurement2', 'TextStuff'}, 2); 

str_format = @(tag, value)sprintf('%s:%s', tag, value);

%# Iterate over the data and print it on the same figure
figure
for i = 1:length(s)

    %# Clear the figure
    clf, set(gcf, 'color', 'white'), axis off

    %# Output the data
    text(0, 1, str_format('Measurement1', num2str(s(i).Measurement1)));
    text(0, 0.9, str_format('Measurement2', num2str(s(i).Measurement2)));
    text(0, 0.8, str_format('TextStuff', s(i).TextStuff))

    %# Wait until the uses press a key
    pause
end
```

Note that [`pause`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/pause.html) forces you to press a key before the next iteration is executed. I've put it there so that you can get the chance see the figure in each iteration.

P.S
Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12250222/1336150) (to another question of yours), you can also output LaTex equations.

---

**EDIT** - some more explanation:

[`cell2struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell2struct.html) is a function that converts a cell array to structure array. In your case, you have `Measurement1`, `Measurement2` and `TextStuff`, each being a cell array holding data about different fields.
All cell arrays are unified into one *array of cell arrays*: `[Measurement1, Measurement2, TextStuff]`. `cell2struct` takes each row from each cell array and forms a struct, the result being stored as *an array of structs*, like so:

```
s = 

2x1 struct array with fields:
    Measurement1
    Measurement2
    TextStuff
```

You can extract the first set of values using `s(1)`, the second using `s(2)`, and so on.
For instance `s(1).TextStuff` gives you `'The cat who ate the rat'`.

I suggest you that type `s` in the MATLAB command prompt to see its contents.

The helper function `str_format` is an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html) that I've created to format the output string for each field. Its input arguments are `tag` (the field name string) and `value` (field value string), which are concatenated together using the [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) command, similar to the [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) function in C/C++.

Comment: EitanT thanks very much. Can you just please expand on the lines where you set s = cell2struct, and the str_format lines? I think I get everything except those two.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/08/01/monitoring-progress-of-a-calculation/) article indicates that you can do it with backspace, though it also seems to say that it won't work with multiple lines.

The principle is that at each iteration you output enough backspace characters to move the cursor to the beginning of your output and then start writing your new output over the old.  You'll have to keep track of the cursor position as you move it back and forth.

Comment: Beware that eventually MATLAB will complain about the command line being too long (including the backspaces) and you will get an `Output truncated` message.

Answer (score 2):

I use 'dispstat' function just for this purpose. It can update the previous output which is a missing function of default 'disp'. Very simple to use. It can be downloaded from here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44673-overwritable-message-outputs-to-commandline-window

***Sample usage:

```
 dispstat('','init'); % One time only initialization
 dispstat(sprintf('Begining the process...'),'keepthis','timestamp');
 for i = 97:100
     dispstat(sprintf('Progress %d%%',i),'timestamp');
     %doing some heavy stuff here
 end
 dispstat('Finished.','keepprev');
```

***Output:

```
11:25:37 Begining the process...
11:25:37 Progress 100%
Finished.
```

All the best