# MATLAB and Math Equations via LaTeX in command window or stand-alone plots?

Tags: matlab, latex, plot

What I would like to do is have math formula output (via LaTeX) in either a complete and separate plot, solely devoted to math equations, or be able to display math equations (again via LaTeX) in the command window itself.

Is this possible in MATLAB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about the command prompt, but you can add LaTex text to MATLAB plots using [`text`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/text.html).
For example, this:

```
figure
set(gcf, 'color', 'white'), axis off     %# Remove axes and set white background
my_text = '$$f_n={x \over \sqrt{2}}$$';
text('units', 'inch', 'position', [-0.5 3.5], 'fontsize', 14, 'color', 'k', ...
    'interpreter', 'latex', 'string', my_text);
```

should give you this:

[image]

I also suggest that you read [this article](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f0-4741.html#bq558_t). This should get you going.

Comment: OMG. Yes. So I have the LaTeX interpreter automatically in MATLAB? I mean, what about specific commands like using \mathbf {} to make stuff bold? Would MATLAB LaTeX understand that? (I am still somewhat new to LaTeX but familiar with it enough to know that there are those extra attachments to it).

Comment: Yes, MATLAB has built-in support for LaTeX. About the specific commands, I haven't checked, but you can play with it yourself and see what happens. You just need to feed the interpreter with the formula and fiddle with the position to get a neat output. Note that when the interpreter has trouble parsing your expression, you'll get an error message in the command prompt.

Comment: Thanks EitanT. I asked a new question on this subject [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250919/expectation-operator-in-matlabs-latex-how-exactly-does-one-do-it), since it might be a big issue. Specifically I am trying to get expectation operator to work in MATLAB's LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

The first is possible using the text command:

```
figure;
text(.1,.9,'\itAe^\alpha^t')
set(gca,'visible','off');
```

Here is a more complete [set of documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f0-4741.html) on using TeX/LaTeX in this way.

Comment: obamaNotBad.jpg. And I take it you can also change the fonts/color the same way as EitanT has done?

Comment: Yup, same answer but he's gone into a lot more detail so it's a better answer :)

Comment: Its nice and elegant. I wonder if perhaps it might be usable for my question here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249579/output-text-numbers-in-matlab-but-overwrite-same-line-in-command-window/12249713#comment16421977_12249713). Perhaps to output all those lines on a plot instead of command window...

Comment: You certainly could, yes, one solution would be to clear the figure window with `cla`, another would simply be to create a white `rectangle` over the area your equation was written.  I'd go with the second way