# How do you use the LaTeX blackboard font in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, text, latex, plot

So, based on my question and solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249639/matlab-and-math-equations-via-latex-in-command-window-or-stand-alone-plots/12250202#comment16422138_12250202), I would like to actually start using LaTeX, in figures as seen. However, one problem I am running into, is that I cannot seem to display the Expectation operator.

From my [research](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=3830), I know that the expectation operator can be displayed as such normally as such:

```
/mathbb{E}
```

However, when I try to use it in MATLAB, nothing prints out.

```
clear all
figure(1); clf(1);
set(gcf, 'color', 'white'), axis off     %# Remove axes and set white background
my_text = '$$ \mathbb{E} $$';
text('units', 'inch', 'position', [-0.5 3.5], 'fontsize', 14, 'color', 'k', ...
    'interpreter', 'latex', 'string', my_text);
```

Now, I know that the \mathbb is some sort of different 'library', but frankly it is quite useful for mathematical formulations. How do I 'include' it in MATLAB? I am lost on this.

Answer (score 7):

You might not have noticed it, but you get an warning message in the command prompt:

> `Warning: Unable to interpret TeX string`

which tells you that MATLAB has trouble parsing your LaTeX expression. More specifically, the [blackboard bold math font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold) (indicated by the `'\mathbb'`) is not supported by MATLAB's built-in LaTeX interpreter (it requires the [amsmath](https://www.ams.org/arc/resources/amslatex-about.html) package).

One way to install this package is described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160415230656/http://www.mathworks.com:80/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/287511) and [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7574110). I'll summarize it for you:

1. Download the AMS-LaTeX package from [here](https://www.ams.org/arc/resources/amslatex-about.html).
2. Modify the m-file `tex.m`, which is located in the `MATLAB root\toolbox\matlab\graphics` folder (backup the file before modifying it):

   2.1. In the `localDecorateInputString` function, modify `standardhead` to include the new packages (marked in bold):

> `standardhead = [' \nofiles \documentclass{mwarticle} \usepackage{amsfonts, amsbsy, amssymb} \begin{document}']`

```
2.2. In the `localGetTeXPath` function, add the paths of where the AMS package files are located (marked in bold), for instance:
```

> `texpath{1} = blah blah blah...
>
> texpath{end+1} = blah blah blah...
>
> texpath{end+1} = 'C:\amslatex';`

3. Copy all `.sty` files of the AMS package to the `MATLAB root\sys\tex` folder.
4. Restart MATLAB.

You should now have the necessary LaTeX font packages installed. I would've gladly checked it out myself if time allowed, it seems promising.

Comment: Thank you so much, however some problems: 1) MATLAB editor is not allowing me so save/modify (Access is denied) the tex.m file. (Even though this is my own computer) - very strange! :-/

Comment: 1) Don't edit the "tex.m" file with the MATLAB editor, use an external editor like Notepad. 2) See bullet #3: you add this direcory to `texpath`.

Comment: Yeah, I jumped ahead of myself with the 3rd step. :-) Let me try all this.

Comment: EitanT, I am unclear as to which ams-latex package to use. There is no amslatex directory from the two parts I downloaded from the link you provided. There is 'amsmath.zip' and 'amscls.zip'. If I unzip them to C:\TeX, I will get 'C:\TeX\amsmath2\' and 'C:\TeX\amscls2\'. I take it you mean the latter is to be included? Also, all .sty from the latter?

Comment: The "amslatex" folder is just an example... It's a folder of your choice. Replace it with "C:\TeX" or "C:\TeX\amsmath2", depending where you unzipped the package files.

Comment: EitanT, Ok, I have accomplished all the above steps. (I used NotePad++). However, when I try to run _any_ tex command now, MATLAB crashes. I did the step 2.1 verbatim, and I did step 2.2 as texpath{end+1} = 'C:\TeX\amsmath2\'; I also copied all the files from 'C:\TeX\amsmath2\tex\latex\amsmath' over to 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\sys'. MATLAB starts ok, but crashes when I try to do any text now. :-/

Comment: Well, I didn't expect a crash. Let me try that myself and I'll look into that. In the meantime, try to remove `amsbsy` and `amssymb` that you've added in step 2.1 and see if it helps. You only need amsfonts as far as my understanding goes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16205/discussion-between-learnaholic-and-eitant)

Comment: One of the link posted the OP says `For Windows, load pfb and pfm font files using the mex function loadfonts.` how to do it?

Comment: IN 2018b, this does not work because the 'tex.m' file only contains a header and no functions

Answer (score 0):

Another way of going about this is to export the figure to an eps file and using the [psfrag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSfrag) to retroactively replace all of your standard E's with their Blackboard Bold equivalents.

```
\psfrag{E}{\mathbb{E}}
```