# How to include a script letter in matlab figure label

Tags: matlab, fonts, latex, matlab-figure, tex

I want to include a script English letter, say `\mathscr{T}` in the Y-axis label in a Matlab figure. Is there an easy way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: You need to add `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` to the preamble of the latex document, either by hand or via the method described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12251619/4050592

Answer (score 5):

Matlab's LaTeX interpreter doesn't seem to recognize `\mathscr`. But it accepts `\mathcal`:

```
ylabel('$\mathcal{T}$','Interpreter','LaTeX','Fontsize',12)
```

Comment: \mathcal{T} doesn't look like a script letter; rather looks like ordinary capital letter. Actually I need \mathscr{T}_{\alpha}. moreover, when I use \mathcal{T}_{\alpha}, alpha doesn't come; a strange symbol comes.

Comment: This might be of help: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/24540

Comment: Sorry, that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Additional note: If you use `sprintf` command (for inputting values of some variables) in the string, you need to put another escape character `\` for MATLAB to recognize commands like `\mathcal{}`, `\in{}`, etc.

```
x = 1:5;
y = sin(x);
plot(x, y);
% regular string does NOT need nother escape character
% xLabel = "t \in [1, 5], t \in \mathcal{N}";
% sprintf needs another escape character
xLabel = sprintf("t \\in [%d, %d], t \\in \\mathcal{N}", x(1), x(end)); 
xlabel(strcat("$", xLabel, "$"), 'Interpreter', 'latex');
yLabel = "sin(t)";
ylabel(strcat("$", yLabel, "$"), 'Interpreter', 'latex');
titleStr = strcat("$\sin(t)$", " for ",  "$", xLabel, "$");
title(titleStr, 'Interpreter', 'latex')
```

[image]