# Plot in matlab, using Latex interpreter

Tags: matlab, plot, latex

I'm try to plot with legend using latex style:

```
legend('$\mathbb{E} $','interpreter','latex','FontSize',18);
```

However, I can not see on the graph, and I get the warning:

> Warning: Unable to interpret TeX string "$\mathbb{E} $"

Comment: I would guess that the Matlab LaTeX interpreter just doesn't have the right package for `\mathbb`. You can try hack it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98760/including-package-to-create-matlab-labels-using-latex but maybe you can find a more standard alternative to `\mathbb`?

Comment: Ron, did my solution fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered. I believe you need to install the mathbb font for the latex interpreter as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12251619/802378) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/122964-character-for-the-real-numbers-matlab).