# Using latex packages in MATLAB markup publish

Tags: matlab, latex, markdown, markup

I'm on Mac OSX 10.10.5 and MATLAB 2015b, and have now spent hours trying to follow various googled instructions for how to import LaTeX packages and use them in within [MATLAB's markup](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html) 'functionality'. The most concise instructions I've found are contained here:

[How do you use the LaTeX blackboard font in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250919/how-do-you-use-the-latex-blackboard-font-in-matlab)

http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7574110

However, nothing has so far worked. I've tried:

1. copying `.cls` files to `/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/sys/tex/latex/base/` (and `/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/sys/tex/`)
2. editing my `/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/sys/tex/mwarticle.cls` to `\usepackage`, `\RequirePackage`, or `\include` as described [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7574110)
3. editing my `/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/toolbox/matlab/graphics/tex.m` file to `\usepackage` or `\RequirePackage` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250919/how-do-you-use-the-latex-blackboard-font-in-matlab)
4. appending `texpath` in `.../tex.m` with downloaded package zips or those with in my Tex distribution e.g. `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath`, `.../source/latex/amsmath`, and `.../doc/latex/amsmath` (both using the `fullfile` function and plain strings)

This is trivial with *free* software `R` and `R Studio` with [R markdown documents](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/). I'm very surprised this is so difficult for *proprietry* software, **especially** given that it has been noted as far back as [five years ago](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/283068)

Comment: @David, with so many scientists and students using (and paying for) `MATLAB` to do assignments and publish research, I'm curious as to why you are surprised. Presumably the `publish` functionality was developed for the reason advertised on the tin.