# How do you use the LaTeX blackboard font in MATLAB? (2019)

Tags: matlab, plot, latex

My question is: How can I use Latex `mathbb` fonts in Matlab.
Furthermore, I have no rights to change Matlab files on my PC.

I do not want to use `psfrag`, suggested sometimes as a solution, since some of my figures generated with Matlab are pictures and they get really big if they are exported to eps.

I am using Matlab 2017a.

Note:
This is a follow up question to [How do you use the LaTeX blackboard font in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250919/how-do-you-use-the-latex-blackboard-font-in-matlab).
The answer to this question seems outdated. My
`MATLAB root\toolbox\matlab\graphics` file contains no matlab commands anymore; it seems to be a precompiled file now.
Thus the approach from the original does not work.

Comment: There is no 2019 release of MATLAB yet. What version of MATLAB are you using? I think that would be a relevant thing to add to your question.

Comment: @SardarUsama To distinguish it from the original question. This question is from year 2019, the old one from year 2012.

Comment: It is clearly written under your question  by the system when it is asked.  So there is absolutely no purpose of writing that yourself