# How can I write with latex character in xlabel in matlab

Tags: matlab, latex, matlab-figure

I would write my xlabel with Latec character so I used this code

```
x = -10:0.1:10;
y = [sin(x); cos(x)];
plot(x,y)
xlabel('$\mathbb{x}$','Interpreter','latex')
```

but I have this warning message

> Warning: Error updating Text.
>
> String scalar or character vector must have valid interpreter syntax:
> $\mathbb{x}$

and the xlabel appear like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCI4n.png

please how I can fix this problem.

Comment: The warning says \mathbb is not a valid TeX interpreter, could you let us know do you want to display?

Comment: The LaTeX support in MATLAB isn't as big as you'd want. Simple stuff works (`A_{i,j}` for instance), but a lot of functions aren't implemented. This one seems to be one of those.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your example is the `mathbb` command, which is not in base Latex. To show this, replace the `\mathbb` with, e.g., `\mathrm`. This will work.

I've never seen an example of adding Latex packages into the Matlab environment. (Update below)

---

You can have a look at this question, which includes a very aggressive potential way to add the package you need. But it's not clear to me if the solution proposed is actually functional.

[How do you use the LaTeX blackboard font in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250919/how-do-you-use-the-latex-blackboard-font-in-matlab)